# current leakage in a laptop

Tags: safety, surge-protection

Current leakage is apparently an issue with some aluminum Macbooks and other laptops.

https://superuser.com/questions/462244/electric-shock-mild-vibrating-sensation-on-macbook-pro-when-charging

Some of the threads related to this topic advise definitely not ignoring what seems like a minor nuisance: https://superuser.com/a/421029/108081

Putting aside the risk of the typical problem, could this be a greater danger with a voltage spike, like during a lightning storm?  Isn't there a surge protector inside the Magsafe adapter?

I've noticed the "hum" effect for a long time but only recently realized it was current leakage.  Regardless of whether or not the Magsafe's ground pin is defective, the 3-pronged cable is not being used, or the outlet isn't properly grounded, if the "hum" is still felt, doesn't this mean there is a defect inside the laptop?  If there were no defect, would proper grounding be unnecessary, as far as risk goes where the Magsafe is the current source?

Comment: We had this ~10 years ago with magnesium-bodied toughbooks, company re-issued us with 3-pin power adapters to replace the 2-pin type and it went away. We measured ~50v on the laptop case with the old type.

Comment: @JohnU, if you were not using the 3-prong ground cable for the outlet, how did you get reliable voltage measurements on the laptop case? What did you use as a reference?

Comment: We used earth as a reference. Specifically, the earth pin on the mains socket in the wall.

Comment: Dell says it's not a problem: http://www.pcworld.com/article/141516/article.html Noticed it right now, and I am barefoot on tile floor. If I raise my feet off the floor, the tingling goes away =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in the absence of any other factors, the secondary of a power transformer will tend to float at half the line voltage, because of the leakage current through the primary-to-secondary capacitance. It really doesn't matter a whole lot whether it's a line-frequency transformer or a high-speed switching transformer, although the capacitance in the latter should be somewhat less.

Normally, this leakage current is conducted directly to ground via the third wire in the line cord, but in a 2-wire cord, this is not possible.

Since the impedance of a capacitor drops with increasing frequency, yes, it could be a concern that the leakage current could be much higher in the presence of fast transients on the primary side. A surge protector inside the power supply will limit the differential voltage across the transformer primary, but it won't have any effect on common-mode voltage offsets. A common-mode choke will have some effect on the latter, but probably not enough to be considered a safety feature; it's mainly there to prevent switching noise from inside the power supply getting back out onto the line.

An electrostatic shield inside the transformer that's tied to the Neutral side of the line input could reduce the leakage considerably, but with nonpolarized plugs (and the possibility that the wall socket is miswired) there'd be a 50-50 chance that it would make the problem worse rather than better.